# Is setting `pointer-events: none;` on header elements an accsssibility issue?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I am updating a site to be more accessible. The former site has `pointer-events: none;` set on all `<h1>` and `<h2>` elements.

Making the transition, is this setting an accessibility issue?

Comment: this might answer your question https://dev.to/alvaromontoro/limit-pointer-events-to-graphic-elements-11cd

Comment: As with anything else disabling `pointer-events` must have a purpose. What is the purpose in your site?

Comment: @RenevanderLende my purpose is to disable text selection if a user were to click on the headers on the site.

Comment: I think you want to use the `user-select` property instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select

Comment: @sol `user-select` seem to be incompatible with accessibility features as  talked bout here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250554/css-user-select-and-accessibility

My goal is to enhance accessibility on the site which currently features `pointer-events` and I couldn't find any info relating `pointer-events` on headers to accessibility.

Comment: "my purpose is to disable text selection if a user were to click on the headers on the site" - Can you explain more about why you want/need to do this? The second answer in that link explains why doing that might hinder accessibility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pointer-events: none` prevent events from emitting. This could cause an issue if you want to make use of those at a later point. If you ever want to listen to an event emitted in your JavaScript code you will be in the somewhat curious situation of them being blocked by your css. So I wouldn't recommend using it without a very good reason.

`pointer-events: none` will disallow events on the child elements. So if there is e.g. a link inside the header end-users will not be able to interact with that link. That would be an accessibility issue.

So there are no accessibility issues using `pointer-events: none` as long as end users won't expect anything to happen when they interact with the element or its descendants.

*PS: Since you mentioned it in the comments: disallowing users to select text is an accessibility issue/restriction by itself.*

Answer (score 0):

### Short Answer

Remove it, it adds no benefit at all on a heading and **may** cause accessibility issues.

### Long Answer

The question you should be asking is **why is it there in the first place?**

A heading shouldn't really have any JavaScript event handlers attached to it and if it does why would you then add `pointer-events: none` to cancel them? If that is why it exists then fix the script.

Obviously I can't see the site but having `pointer-events: none;` on a heading is like adding `role="presentation"` to a `<div>`....it serves no purpose....assuming the site doesn't have underlying issues that necessitate its use.

The only reason I could see someone adding this is if either there is a problem with the site and they brute forced their way around it (so events are bubbling up incorrectly due to a poor selector for example) or you have some strange function operating (maybe a clipboard copy function that for some reason you wouldn't want to work on Headings?).

While it **shouldn't** cause accessibility issues, as the items shouldn't be interactive, I would encourage you to remove it if you can, it serves no real purpose.

With regards to your comment about "my purpose is to disable text selection if a user were to click on the headers on the site."...`pointer-events` wont do that as you can see in the fiddle at the end of this answer...**you can still select the text** but it doesn't register events (click on top heading nothing happens, bottom heading will log to console).

As you also pointed out, `user-select` can cause usability issues for people who might select text to have it read out to them (learning difficulty, second language etc.) or to help them focus on a sentence at a time (dyslexia for example) etc. etc.

**If someone wants to select the text to make it easier to read then let them!**

`pointer-events: none` should only really be used to allow people to click through an item to an item beneath that is interactive.

#### fiddle to illustrate text selection is still possible with `pointer-events: none`

```js
$('h2').on('click', function(e){
   console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 style="pointer-events: none">test</h2>
<h2>test</h2>
```

Comment: *If someone wants to select the text to make it easier to read then let them!* ... **or even copy content** ... Our sites are so extremely interesting that everyone should be encouraged to copy everything for later reference!

Comment: I cannot tell if you are saying you should prevent people from copying content or that allowing them to select text is a good thing so they can copy text.

Comment: Oh, but I never meant to use it for protection, but more for mouse-click-happy users. Esp. with a lot of clickable items on the page to prevent them from inadvertedly selecting text all the time. *I saw your little rant pass by*: don't worry, I understand what you were getting at. My eyesight has been fading over the years and see myself zooming in a page to 150% (and over) to be able to read. Thank Google for that, with their default fontsize of 14px the rest of the world seems to have copied. So I'd go the extra mile to make a site readable for all. FYI: 64% wears vision aids. I research...

Comment: And...to add to my comment: I would even want to have a W3C specified default button in the corner of EACH site that triggers some 'I-cannot-read-your-darned-site' configuration. Not just the browser settings. Mandatory. FYI2: 64% of **the entire** world population, adults and kids alike. FYI3: I **always** use CSS `html { font-size: calc(0.625vmin + 0.75rem) }` to calculate the base fontsize for a device using linear equation **y=mx+b** with points **p1(320,14) p2(1280,20)**. So, I get you and I do not take offence at all... We cool?

Comment: Oh and I was being serious, people should be able to select anything on a site, whatever the reason. I often do. And site protection? Who are they kidding, we've got Dev.Tools.

Comment: yeah it was one of those where I misread what you had written and then realised it might not have been sarcasm. I believe it is the law in blugaria or somewhere like that they have to have site settings....would be great if that went world wide. Yeah we definitely cool, like I said was my misunderstanding your comment, was 130am so I was obviously a grumpy guss!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would prevent users to select text, instead of using `pointer-events: none` on designated HTML elements:

- prevent **all** user selection on the entire page
- allow selection only where selection of content is applicable

Like this:

```css
/* prohibit user from selecting text (put in <body>), esp. convenient for 'click-happy' users... */
[no-select] { -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none }
[do-select] { -webkit-user-select: text; -moz-user-select: text; -ms-user-select: text; user-select: text; cursor: auto }
/* enable user to select text (put in specific elements) */
```

```html
<body no-select>
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, exerci dolorem est ad. Sumo rebum prompta vim ad. Legendos expetendis id sed. Ex ius quem accusamus, pri et
        deleniti copiosae.</p>
    <p>Cu vel debet nobis, repudiare deseruisse reprehendunt usu ad. Ex elit idque nam. Omnis munere detraxit mei te, eu labore appareat verterem
        est. Mel ex oporteat consectetuer.</p>
    <p><b do-select>THIS IS SELECTABLE, DO TRY WITH mouse or [Ctrl-A]</b>&nbsp; THE REST OF THE ENTIRE TEXT, HOWEVER, NOT!!! Pro ea nonumy integre, mel at solum corpora. Id viris audiam repudiare cum, pri dolore appareat ex, per propriae detracto tacimates ex.
        Elitr sapientem quo et, usu suas porro tibique cu. Iusto causae eos et, tota principes interesset et eos. Similique intellegam cum ei, unum
        qualisque mel et, regione verterem delicatissimi qui ut. Aliquam incorrupte ea pro, vel veritus consequat id.</p>
    <p>Pri te amet electram. Tation commodo minimum cu pri, utamur minimum id pri. No legimus atomorum vim. Vix id putent iuvaret salutandi, mel
        phaedrum conceptam ut.</p>
</body>
```